# how to configure multiple shell scripts on Jenkins and run them without waiting for the other script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins, ssh

I am trying to run a shell script from jenkins which is of the following form

`ssh host1 'nohup path/script.sh &'`

`ssh host2 'nohup path/script.sh &'`

`ssh host3 'nohup path/script.sh &'`

`sleep 90`

`ssh host1 'nohup path/script.sh &'`

`ssh host2 'nohup path/script.sh &'`

`ssh host3 'nohup path/script.sh &'`

I want to run first three scripts parallely at the same time and then sleep for a while and start processing the next three scripts and at the end print output for all the 6 scripts in the same order to jenkins build log. I am using nohup for the script to run on the back ground and doesn't want to output the log of the script to any file. Dont want to use `nohup script.sh >dev/null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `ssh` processes should run in backround, not the remote process. Second, use the `wait` builtin instead of `sleep` (which is pretty unstable).

```
# Create temporary files for the commmand's output
output1=$(mktemp)
output2=$(mktemp)
output3=$(mktemp)

> "$output1" ssh host1 'path/script.sh' &
> "$output2" ssh host2 'path/script.sh' &
> "$output3" ssh host3 'path/startNode.sh' &
wait && cat "$output1" "$output2" "$output3"

# Cleanup tempfiles
rm  "$output1" "$output2" "$output3"

... more stuff
```

I'm using temporary files for the output of each command. Once all job has been finished the output get's concatenated and printed.

Comment: I need the output to be printed as well for each shell script.. By doing the above.. the job runs.. but the output of each shell doesn't get printed on the job/log

Comment: The log should be displayed once the jobs have finished?

Comment: the log of 3 different scripts are mixing up, would like to have them seperated

Comment: I have tried the above script. The script is failing. I had `output1=$(temp1)`
`output2=$(tempfile)` .. it is failing at line2 looking for temp1 file saying temp1 not found at line 2

Comment: `output1=$(tempfile)
output2=$(tempfile)
output3=$(tempfile)` Its failing at line 2.

Comment: /tmp/hudson8656879817066728675.sh: line 2: tempfile: command not found
+ output1=
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Please try `mktemp` instead of `tempfile`. Does it work now?

Comment: You are welcome. I'll add `mktemp` to my answer, looks like `tempfile` is not that widely deployed. (It's part of debianutils, never knew that)